# Save/Mail PDF document loaded in UIWebView called by Javascript

Tags: javascript, objective-c, pdf, webview

The situation is a bit of a puzzle to me, I'll try the best to explain myself.

There's a webpage that generates a custom PDF document when certain button is clicked (button calls a javascript function that creates the PDF document). In desktop version of said webpage, when button is clicked the PDF is downloaded (not shown).

Now I'm loading said webpage into an UIWebView, the problem comes when the button is clicked. The PDF is loaded then shown in the webview.

I would like to mail that PDF or download it as an image (simple taking image from webview results in pixelated "PDF" that cannot be zoomed in, therefore becomes humanly unreadable).

Since the PDF is generated in a Javascript function in the server side I can't seem to obtain the PDF url to manually generate the PDF from Objective-C with the URL info.

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting link of pdf that is on server side??

if yes then write below code

```
NSString *pathStr=[dd objectForKey:@"pdfKey"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:pathStr];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *pdfPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myLocalFileName.pdf"];
[data writeToFile:pdfPath atomically:YES];
```

let me know whether is it working or not...

Happy Coding!!!!

Comment: nope, the PDF is called within a Javascript function on the server side and I cannot seem to obtain the destination URL